# Insanely Twisted Shadow Planet corrupted save recovery

Tags: games-for-windows-live, insanely-twisted-planet

Is there a way to recover my corrupted save file on Insanely Twisted Shadow Planet on the platform Games for Windows?

After defeating the Mechanical Room boss, I proceeded through the air vent on the left to the next area.  Then I attempted to save and I was told the save file is corrupted and I would need to start over.  [Other people have this problem too.](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2665702)

Am I out of luck?  Or is there a way to start the game where I left off?